# How to check for a null value in a variable passed as a reference

Tags: ibm-doors

In DXL, how do I check whether a variable holds a null value after passing it to a function as a reference? The usual method using `(null variableName)` doesn't seem to be working properly:

```
void valueBasedNullTest(Buffer b) {
  print "Value based: "
  print "null b => "
  if (null b) {
    print "true"
  } else {
    print "false"
  }
  print "\n"
}

void referenceBasedNullTest(Buffer &b) {
  print "Reference based: "
  print "null b => "
  if (null b) {
    print "true"
  } else {
    print "false"
  }
  print "\n"
}

Buffer someBuffer = null
valueBasedNullTest(someBuffer)
referenceBasedNullTest(someBuffer)
```

Result:

```
Value based: null b => true
Reference based: null b => false
```

I'm currently running Rational DOORS 9.2.

Why is this happening, and how can I work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here's what I ultimately went with. This answer is based on [a discussion I found on the Rational DOORS DXL Forum](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014458406) about how to check for unassigned variables.

I still can't quite wrap my head around exactly how it works, but my understanding is that it's checking the memory address of whatever variable you pass it, and basing its answer on the fact that null objects seem to always have an address of 0. (Feel free to prove me wrong.)

```
/*
Regular null check returns incorrect results in DOORS 9.2 under the following condition:

    void referenceBasedNullTest(Buffer &b) {
      print "Reference based: "
      print "null b => "
      if (null b) {
        print "true"
      } else {
        print "false"
      }
      print "\n"
    }

    Buffer someBuffer = null
    referenceBasedNullTest(someBuffer)

isNull works correctly in this case.
*/
bool isNull(_ &value) {
  int *intRef = (addr_ ((addr_ (value)) int))
  return (0 == *intRef)
}
```

In any case, it seems to work fine for my purposes.

Quick test:

```
int nullInt = null
int blankInt = 0
int unassignedInt
int goodInt = 42

print "isNull(nullInt)\t\t=> "     isNull(nullInt) "\n"
print "isNull(blankInt)\t\t=> "    isNull(blankInt) "\n"
print "isNull(goodInt)\t\t=> "     isNull(goodInt) "\n"
print "isNull(unassignedInt)\t=> " isNull(unassignedInt) "\n"

print "\n"

Skip nullSkip = null
Skip blankSkip = create
Skip unassignedSkip

print "isNull(nullSkip)\t\t=> "     isNull(nullSkip) "\n"
print "isNull(blankSkip)\t\t=> "    isNull(blankSkip) "\n"
print "isNull(unassignedSkip)\t=> " isNull(unassignedSkip) "\n"
```

Result:

```
isNull(nullInt)        => true
isNull(blankInt)       => true  // Note: 0 is null for int values
isNull(goodInt)        => false
isNull(unassignedInt)  => false

isNull(nullSkip)       => true
isNull(blankSkip)      => false
isNull(unassignedSkip) => false
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem you are talking about, it does seem very strange. The way I would handle it is:

```
void referenceBasedNullTest(Buffer &b) {
  print "Reference based: "
  print "null b => "
  if (length(b) <=0) {
    print "true"
  } else {
    print "false"
  }
  print "\n"
}

Buffer someBuffer = create
//valueBasedNullTest(someBuffer)
referenceBasedNullTest(someBuffer)
delete(someBuffer)
```

This makes sure the buffer exists, but you can still test to see if it has anything in it. Don't forget to delete the Buffer at the end of use.

Comment: This doesn't really fulfill the requirements per se, since it avoids using null in the first place, but it might be an acceptable compromise if there's no other solution...

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @Ajedi32 works well except in two cases:

```
isNull(null) // --> causes an access violation

void foo(DxlObject &o) {
    isNull(o);
}
foo(null)    // --> causes an access violation
```

While one can argue, that the first case is somewhat absurd, the latter happens frequently when I test for null inside some other functions.

**Solution:**
I don't really understand what the `addr_` function does, I'm assuming it returns the address of the given argument.
In case of the example above, `addr_` returns the values `-1` and `0`, which probably are never valid addresses, so I have modified the function as follows and got it working for my use cases:

```
bool isNull(_ &value) {
    if((addr_ value) == 0 || (addr_ value) == -1) {
        return true;
    }
    int *intRef = (addr_ ((addr_ (value)) int))
    return (0 == *intRef)
}
```

Quick Test:

```
bool foo(DxlObject &o) {
    return isNull(o);
}

int nullInt = null
int blankInt = 0
int unassignedInt
int goodInt = 42

print "isNull(nullInt)\t\t=> "     isNull(nullInt) "\n"
print "isNull(blankInt)\t\t=> "    isNull(blankInt) "\n"
print "isNull(goodInt)\t\t=> "     isNull(goodInt) "\n"
print "isNull(unassignedInt)\t=> " isNull(unassignedInt) "\n"

print "\n"

Skip nullSkip = null
Skip blankSkip = create
Skip unassignedSkip

print "isNull(nullSkip)\t\t=> "     isNull(nullSkip) "\n"
print "isNull(blankSkip)\t\t=> "    isNull(blankSkip) "\n"
print "isNull(unassignedSkip)\t=> " isNull(unassignedSkip) "\n"
bool b = isNull(null);
print "isNull(null)\t\t=> "         b "\n"
b = foo(null);
print "foo(null)\t\t\t=> "          b "\n"
```